# MS SQL Job running stored procedure over linked server with windows auth

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication, linked-server

I have SRV01 server with SQLSRV01 installation and SQLDB01 database. On that server I got SQL Server Agent service running under windows SQLAgent account (can't be changed). Also I set up linked server to SQLSRV02 located on SRV02 machine which uses current security context for authentication. I got windows user DOMAIN\IntegrationUser01 which has access to both databases on both servers.
Then I created simple stored procedure which read data from remote table and write it to local (tested and working when I log in to SQLSRV01 as IntegrationUser01).
At the end I set up job to execute that stored procedure. I set DOMAIN\IntegrationUser01 as owner of JOB and also as user to run step as (Step -> Properties -> Advenced -> Run as).

It doesn't work. Job execution ends with exception:

> Linked servers cannot be used under impersonation without a mapping
>   for the impersonated login.

As I understand SQLAgent account in 1st step impersonate itself as IntegrationUser01 to run JOB and then needs to be able to delegate those credential over linked server to SRV02 for authentication. Since there is no Kerberos protocol to handle 2nd hoop, it looks for mapping to SQL User on SQLSRV02 server which doesn't exists.

Is there any possibility to set up such architecture without Kerberos ? or I'm just doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these solutions if it is possible:

1) provide access to your SQL agent service account on the linked server

2) Goto server object > linked servers > select server & go to properties > in security tab provide user name that having access rights on the linked server.

Comment: 1.) I am working under client requirements. Until I prove something can't be done I can't use workarounds.
2.) It's not so simple.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution and used SQL Server Agent Proxy. Unfortunately it doesn't work with T-SQL JOB Steps but workaround is super simple.

1.) You need to save DOMAIN\IntegrationUser01 windows credentials (Internal_SQL_Credential_Name in scr's below) in SQL Server (Security -> Credentials)

2.) You set up proxy in SQL Server Agent Node for CmdExe subsystem (Internal_SQL_Proxy_Name in scr's below) and point it to created credentials.

3.) For proxy you adding principal login. Since this is sql windows auth you select "DOMAIN\IntegrationUser01"

4.) You change step type to: CmdExe and Run as to: Internal_SQL_Proxy_Name (by default it's SQL Server Agent Service Account).

5.) As command you set up: SQLCMD -Q"EXEC DataBaseName.SchemaName.StoredProcedure" -E -S ServerName

[image: Credentials]
[image: Proxy]
[image: JOB]